# How does a view at HMVC output its data?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, hmvc

I'm currently reading a lot about HMVC and try to learn it. Haven't used it so far because I'd like to understand it before I'm trying to code something (I wanna try to make a lil mini framework just to understand everything before I use some big known framework, don't like to use things I don't understand 100%).

So my question is how some view of a module would output its data. There are a lot of graphics but they only show the links between the small MVC triads and the controllers of the modules.

So if I have a MVC on top for my page (level #1) and I have some modules (level #2) the request would go to level #1 and the controller there would decide what happens next BUT whats about the output? Would the level #2 view just output its data? Or would it save it like $outputModuleXy = file_get_contents($templateName) and return it to the level #2 controller who would pass it to the level #1 controller so the level #1 view is responsable for the output?

I'm kinda confused about that because I can't seem to find some tutorial where the dataflow is described and how the view data from the modules get their way up to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

**HMVC** is a **Hierarchical model–view–controller** which means that you have many modules in your application. each module is MVC by itself. so the confusion you have about outputting data, is simple. each **(Level)** as you named it. has it's own view - model - controller.
so it's simply will be outputted in its view.
let's say that you have a system which has a big credential on **login** part. which consists of many levels of login types. and you wanted to separate the login part into separate MVC module which will leads you to structure you app as **HMVC**.
now if I entered your app. the **First Respond Module** will jump to take care of me. but then I want to enter my membership area. where I can add users or modify their privileges. so your controller will call the module who handles this area which is another MVC layer. the outputs here is provided by this module's view.

There are many in-deep functionality in **HMVC** you have to read about it in tutorials.

there are many resources about **HMVC** you can take a look at:

1. [tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/) - talking about it within **codeigniter** explanation.
2. [inviqa](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/) -  talking about it within **kohana php** explanation
3. [javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2000/jw-0721-hmvc.html?page=1) - talking about the paper itself.